# eps import wrong title in graphic \pi looks like \neq

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps, matlab

I need to import a figure from Matlab. 
I export it as an [`.eps`](http://www.mediafire.com/download/an3jt88abbtbyux/11eps.eps).
I use `epstopdf` to import it in LaTeX and for some unknown reasons the greek letter pi in the title of the plot that looks ok in the `.eps` does not look ok anymore in the output `.pdf` and I don't know why (see attachment).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, pt=9]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}

\title{Dum De Dum}

\author{Irene}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{11eps}
\caption{Confronto MSE e CRB nella stima della frequenza di $\omega_1$, $NF=200$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: [image: Output pdf]
EDIT2: With `matlab2tikz` (as suggested in the comments) it works properly. 
It seems not to work fine for me running pdflatex as it is but the reason is to me totally mysterious.

EDIT3: The question is to me absolutely clear (as it is, probably, to the upvoters), if it is not please specify the problems so that I can maybe help to solve them. Closing a perfectly clear question just because it has been open for long time without any contribution does not seem to be the way to go.

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot of the outcome after conversion would help?

Comment: Not a direct solution to the problem, but are you aware of [`matlab2tikz`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz)?

Comment: I have the file from your link, your code and run pdflatex over it -- pi looks like it should.

Comment: It does not look ok for me (see the edit) Any ideas? I am giving a look at matlab2tikz and no, I was not aware of it. Thank you.

Comment: @Irene: Yes, `\pi` has been exchanged to `\neq` -- that is strange. However, on my computer, this does not happen.

Comment: @Irene: with matlab2tikz you get TikZ code of your graphic, hence if something goes wrong like in your case, you have the possibility to edit the code.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I got it to work with matlab2tikz, so thanks, I leave the question open if that's ok with you because I would like to know what's wrong with that code. Would you mind?

Comment: @Irene: not at all, let us keep it open. Happy you made it working with matlab2tikz :) BTW: the italian group has some documentation about TikZ; you can find them in [http://www.guitex.org/home/it/doc](http://www.guitex.org/home/it/doc) under the paths "Guide per iniziare" and "Guide GuIT Tematiche".